# How do I create a strip plot similar to this using vega-lite?

Tags: python, missing-data, vega-lite, altair

I'm interested in being able to recreate this multidimensional strip plot below, generated by the [Missing Numbers](https://github.com/ResidentMario/missingno) python library, using vega-lite, and I'm looking for a few pointers on how I might do this. The code to generate the image below looks a bit like this snippet:

```
>>> from quilt.data.ResidentMario import missingno_data
>>> collisions = missingno_data.nyc_collision_factors()
>>> collisions = collisions.replace("nan", np.nan)

>>> import missingno as msno
>>> %matplotlib inline
>>> msno.matrix(collisions.sample(250))
```

[image: Missing Number multi dimensional strip plot]

For each column, there is a mark shown for a specific combination of the index, and where the data is null, or not null.

When I look through a gallery of charts created by Altair, I see this horizontal strip plot, which seems to be presenting a similar kind of information, but I'm not sure how to express the same idea.

The viz below is showing a mark when there is data that matches a given combination of horse power and cylinder size - the horsepower and cylinder are encoded into the x and y channels.

[image: Altair strip plot]

I'm not show how I'd express the same for the cool nullity matrix thing, and I think I need some pointers here.

I get that I can reset and index to come up with a y index, but it's not clear to me how to index of the sample is encoded in the Y channel, I'm not sure how I'd populate the x-axis with a column listing the null/not null results. Is this a thing I'd need to do before it gets to vega-lite, or does vega support it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this after reshaping your data with a [Fold Transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/fold.html). It looks something like this using Altair:

```
import numpy as np
import quilt
quilt.install("ResidentMario/missingno_data")

from quilt.data.ResidentMario import missingno_data
collisions = missingno_data.nyc_collision_factors()
collisions = collisions.replace("nan", np.nan)
collisions = collisions.set_index("Unnamed: 0")
```

```
import altair as alt

alt.Chart(collisions.sample(250)).transform_window(
    index='row_number()'
).transform_fold(
    collisions.columns.to_list()
).transform_calculate(
    defined="isValid(datum.value)"
).mark_rect().encode(
    x=alt.X('key:N',
        title=None,
        sort=collisions.columns.to_list(),
        axis=alt.Axis(orient='top', labelAngle=-45)
    ),
    y=alt.Y('index:O', title=None),
    color=alt.Color('defined:N',
        legend=None,
        scale=alt.Scale(domain=["true", "false"], range=["black", "white"])
    )
).properties(
    width=800, height=400
)
```

[image]